# How can I mount an EFS volume to a kubernetes cluster running on AWS ubuntu18 instances as Persistent Volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, amazon-efs, kubernetes-pvc

I have created my Kubernetes cluster with 1 master node and 2 worker nodes all on ubuntu18 EC2 instances on AWS. I wanted to create a persistent volume for that cluster and got to know about EFS but I am finding it difficult to mount it as there is no specific documentation for it.

https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs

I have used the above link for creating an efs-provisioner and have given all my EFS credentials like EFS-id and region-name, etc and it also created a pod efs-provisioner but the PVC volume it created is in pending state always.
And after creating a deployment file for my application when I am trying to connect to the volume by using the Persistent Volume Claim it is not deploying.

These steps are really complicated and hard to execute so if there is any simpler way to execute this task please share it with me.
Even if it is a blog or video which gives better understanding of this topic please share it with me, I will really appreciate it.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The [github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs)  you mentioned is no longer being maintained and has been archived by the owner. There are 2 other projects related to `nfs` provisioners (as `efs` is based on `nfs`):

- [**nfs-ganesha-server-and-external-provisioner**](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-ganesha-server-and-external-provisioner)

> **`nfs-ganesha-server-and-external-provisioner`** is an out-of-tree dynamic provisioner for Kubernetes 1.14+. You can use it to quickly & easily deploy shared storage that works almost anywhere. Or it can help you write your own out-of-tree dynamic provisioner by serving as an example implementation.

- [**nfs-subdir-external-provisioner**](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner)

> **`NFS subdir external provisioner`** is an automatic provisioner that use your *existing and already configured* NFS server to support dynamic provisioning of Kubernetes Persistent Volumes via Persistent Volume Claims. Persistent volumes are provisioned as `${namespace}-${pvcName}-${pvName}`.

And as you are using aws, another option for you is using [EFS in EKS cluster](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-persistent-storage/). Hope this information will help you find a working solution.

Comment: I have tried it and the efs-provisioner pod was created but while creating the deployment I don't know why but the container was hanging in the containercreating state and in the logs it was showing "Unable to attach the volume : waiting for the condition"

Comment: while troubleshooting I found one thing that while initializing the cluster we have to provide cloud-provider=aws  in the config-file but I don't know how to do that. I tried by directly using the default config-file and editing it to accomodate the cloud-provider=aws but it was giving error

Comment: Which repo did you choose?

Comment: nfs-subdir-external-provisioner

Comment: Just now I have tried one more time and I succeeded. I have one doubt that after creating the above efs-provisioner when I deployed 2 diff applications with the same pvc it was perfectly sharing storage but the efs I have connected to it was already having some files in it but I didn't see that files in the mounted directory, why is that..??

Comment: Check if the provisioner created new subdirs, and that's why you can't see those existing files. There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/issues/169). Let me know the result, please.